# Is there any way to post parameters individually without NSData for Json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Is there any way to post parameters individually without NSData for Json

Here is my code:

```
NSData *jsonInputData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:datDict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
[req setHTTPBody: jsonInputData];
```

instead of jsonInputData can we append individual params?

Comment: You can send request as a query parameter simply by appending " ?parameter name = value " if request method is of type GET. If the request type is post and if it expects JSON you have to convert it to NSData

Comment: The request type is POST

Comment: @sireesha send data with dictionary

Comment: @Jigar I am sending data itself. But as per the requirement, I need to pass the parameters individually to HTTPBody. I am not understanding how to pass those parameters .I tried using NSString type but the app crashes. So is there a way to pass parameters individually to HTTPBody ?PFB code                                                                                    NSString* jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonInputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; [req SETHTTPBody: jsonString];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *params=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"mobile=%@& uid=%@ & sim_code=%@ & operator_code=%@ & operator_name=%@ & otp=%@",num,uuid,dail,dailingcode,carrier.carrierName,randomCode];


   NSString *mainUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",urlLinkA,methodName];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:mainUrl];
    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //NSString * params=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"mobile=%@",[self.reqnum text]];

    NSLog(@"parameter %@",parameters);
    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[parameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                       completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                           NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                                           if(error == nil)
                                                           {
```

Comment: [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable connectionError) {
        if(data)
            [self jsonGetParse:data];
    }];

Comment: but the method which I replaced is deprecated one can I use further

Comment: replace with this :  it will work I guess [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data,NSURLResponse *response,NSError *error)
 {
 // Block Body 
 }];